# How to stop the innodb log files?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to prevent mysql database from creation of innodb log files. can we delete or stop it ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to disable InnoDB altogether, since these files are required by InnoDB.

To disable InnoDB, add the following two params into the MySQL configuration file, then restart MySQL:

```
[mysqld]

skip_innodb
default_storage_engine=MyISAM
```

This assumes you don't already have any InnoDB tables.

This concludes the answer - but I'm curious: why would you want to disable InnoDB?

Comment: No.. Just I want to delete this log file /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0

Comment: This log file is required by InnoDB. It is also fixed in size -- not as if it would grow forever. It is part of the transaction system.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to do that?
The log mechanism is part of the durability and consistency of the engine, therefor shutting it off will not allow the DB to recover from a crash (the data since the last checkpoint until the crash will not be recoverable, and you'll find critical errors in the log).
Because of the engine design - log files are a must.
What is your need? maybe there is a better solution for your need.
For example - are memory tables a good solution for you (if you don't care about the content, only the speed)?

Comment: in my case it is to small and creates problem and I cannot change size of it du to use AWS